# Add header to PostHttp processsor Apache Nifi

Tags: post, apache-nifi

Im trying to add a custom header in my post request header in apache nifi, I have seen that in the configuration tab there's Attributes to send as http header (regex) I'm not very familiar with regex, any idea how to add a header and its value like the following : token : READ  ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[PostHttp](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PostHTTP/index.html)'s "Attributes to Send as HTTP Headers (Regex)" property can accept a regex, but it will work just fine to specify a single attribute name like `token`.  If you had multiple attribute you wanted to name, you could use a pipe to "or" them together:

```
token|attrib2|attrib3
```

For each attribute you selected, the attribute name and value are sent as the HTTP header name and value.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i see how to add the attribute token but where I can put its value ?

Comment: You configure the attribute name and value prior to PostHttp.  In PostHttp, you are specifying which attributes should be sent as additional headers.