# Static header for PostHTTP/InvokeHTTP processor - NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to add a static header to my `PostHTTP/InvokeHTTP` processor.

As I have gone through the documentation and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40754345/add-header-to-posthttp-processsor-apache-nifi), it seems like we will support only the attributes from the input `flowfile` of the processor.

I tried adding the header in the below format, in the attribute *Attributes to Send as HTTP Headers (Regex)* / *Attributes to Send* . But it didn't workout.

```
"key:value"
```

How can I set a static header which is not part of the `flowfile`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In InvokeHttp, any user-defined properties will also be sent as headers. Go to the configure screen of InvokeHttp, and on the properties tab, click the + icon in the top right to add a property. Make the name of the property the name of the header and the value of the property the value of the header.

Comment: Thanks @Byran. I will be able to verify it, once this is fixed, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45738129/error-for-sslcontextservice-for-posthttp-invokehttp-nifi